# Macro used on multiple workbooks to reset sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to write a macro that will reset sheets within a workbook that has multiple sheets. Essentially here is what it will do:

**1. clear cells on Sheet1 B3, B6 and B9 of active workbook where macro is activated** (all file names will be different. For example lets call these workbooks "Active")

**2. open template file** (let's call this file Partner_Checklist.xlsm since this file will be consistent throughout the macro)

**3. select all content in Partner_Checklist.xlsm from sheet1**

**4. Copy all content in Partner_Checklist.xlsm sheet 1**

**5. Paste content into Active workbook in Sheet2**

**6. Close Partner_Checklist.xlsm**

This will be used for a project where every quarter we need to use these workbooks to perform an audit. Workbooks need to be cleared of the previous review and if the template is updated, make it easier to update across all workbooks.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: "I am looking to write a macro" - OK so what *precisely* is the problem?  Are you stuck on one particular step?  Have you tried recording a macro and looking at the resulting code?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I can think of is to use the macro recorder, and save a macro of  the operations you want to repeat. If you are unsure of what that is, you have to have the developer tab enabled on your ribbon, then the option to use macro recorder will be on the top left. Here is a link on how to enable the developer tab.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx

Record yourself doing it once, then save the macro. Now you can execute that macro anytime, and it will perform the exact operations that you performed while recording.